# Unexpected indent in subprocess call

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, indentation

I had the impression that `exit(0)` signaled to the Python interpreter to return 0 to the system. For example,

```
from subprocess import check_call
check_call('python3 -c "exit(0)"', shell=True)  # returns 0
```

But

```
check_call(['/usr/bin/python3', '-c "exit(0)"'])
```

returns 1:

```
>>> check_call(['/usr/bin/python3', '-c "exit(0)"'])
  File "<string>", line 1
    "exit(0)"
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 581, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/python3', '-c "exit(0)"']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

I can't tell where any spaces are sneaking in. What's going on?

Comment: Have you tried splitting `-c "exit(0)"` into two separate args?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Oops. I guess that's the answer.

Comment: Each command line argument should be passed as a separate list item. You could generate a draft list from a shell command using:`shlex.split('python3 -c "exit(0)"')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that if the `-c` flag is not followed by another argument, the rest of the current argument is interpreted as Python code:

```
>> python3 -c 'print("yes")'
yes

>> python3 '-cprint("yes")'
yes

>> python3 '-c print("yes")'
  File "<string>", line 1
    print("yes")
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

So both of the following should work, although the first variant feels most idiomatic/safe:

```
check_call(['/usr/bin/python3', '-c', 'exit(0)'])
check_call(['/usr/bin/python3', '-cexit(0)'])
```